# How do i extract individual frames from videos using ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-streaming

I have a bunch of videos downloaded from Youtube and I would like to extract frames from them. The current command I am using is:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -an -s qvga %06d.png
```

But I also want to set the -r and -t option. I want the fps to be the fps of each video, and the duration time is their duration. I know that if I don't set the -r option, the default is 25 fps.

So could anyone help? how to add the -r and -t option? and is there any better and accurate way to obtain individual frames from videos? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need to set duration (`-t`) or frame rate (`-r`) when outputting images. By default `ffmpeg` will output all of the images.

Other notes:

- If you want to limit the duration, such as only wanting the images from the first 3 seconds, then use `-t 3`.
- If you want to limit the number of output frames, such as only wanting the first 100 frames, then use `-frames:v 100`.
- Individual images do not have a frame rate. If you add `-r`, then `ffmpeg` will duplicate or drop frames if `-r` is different than the input frame rate. Omitting `-r` will output all images.
- You don't need `-an` when outputting images.
- Using the [scale filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale) is more flexible than `-s`. It can prevent stretching because it can preserve the aspect ratio: `-vf scale=320:-1`

Comment: Thanks a lot, @LordNeckbeard, it really save my day. Your answer is clear and helpful, I appreciate it.